# Convert a column vector into a extended diagonal matrix

Tags: r, matrix, vector, diagonal

Consider the following column vector:

```
vec <- rbind(c(0.5),c(0.6))
```

I want to convert it into the following 4x4 diagonal matrix:

```
0.5   0   0    0 
  0 0.6   0    0 
  0   0 0.5    0
  0   0   0  0.6
```

I know I can do it by the following code:

```
dia <- diag(c(vec,vec))
```

But what if I want to convert it into a 1000x1000 diagonal matrix. Then the code above is so efficient. Maybe I can use `rep`, but I am not totally sure how to do it. How can I do it more efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one other way using recycling:

```
diag(c(vec), length(vec)*2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is already good enough, here is another way by initialising the matrix and using `rep` to fill diagonals.

```
n <- 4
mat <- matrix(0, ncol = n, nrow = n)
diag(mat) <- rep(vec, n/2)

mat
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]  0.5  0.0  0.0  0.0
#[2,]  0.0  0.6  0.0  0.0
#[3,]  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.0
#[4,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.6
```

and following your approach you could do

```
diag(rep(vec, n/2))
```

Comment: Just a small note, but with `rep(vec, n/2)` it could be even nicer :)

Comment: Yes, that is a great note :-)
Thank you both!

Comment: Thanks @tmfmnk , I thought `vec` will always be of size `n/2`.